Topological entropy equal zero in countable dynamics
Topological entropy
Let $X$ a compact metric space with metric $d$. Let $f:X \to X$ a continuous function. For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ define
$$ d_n(x,y) = \max_{0\leq k \leq n-1} d(f^k(x), f^k(y))$$
We say that $K \subseteq X$ is  $(n,\epsilon)$ separated if for all $x \neq y \in K$ implies $d_n(x,y) \geq \epsilon$. Now, we denote by $\mathcal{K}(n,\epsilon) = \max |K|$ where the maximum is taken over all $(n,\epsilon)$ separated sets in $X$ and $|\cdot|$ means cardinality of $K$.
So, the $\epsilon$-entropy is given by
$$h_\epsilon(f) = \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{log(\mathcal{K}(n, \epsilon))}{n}$$.
The topological entropy of $f$ is given by
$$h(f) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} h_{\epsilon}(f) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{log(\mathcal{K}(n, \epsilon))}{n}$$
I have read multiple papers where claim that if the space $X$ is countable (with the other conditions), then the topological entropy is zero and reference in many cases the following book: Ergodic Theory on Compact Spaces, M. Denker, C. Grillenberger, K. Sigmund. However I don't find such result in the book. I don't know if this stament is trivial from the definition and because $X$ is countable. But I haven't managed to do the proof.
If you have any suggestions on how I can prove that under these conditions you always have zero entropy I would appreciate it. Sorry for my english, I'm not native, I'm practicing...
